# What does '^' mean in this context?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Literally just launched SSH on my Rasberry Pi and have no idea what it means.

I'm editing a file from console and it says press ^X to exit, what exactly should I be pressing? I'm on windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

`^` is a convention for representing <kbd>Control</kbd> key. Wikipedia mentions this in article on [Control key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key):

```
Traditional notation. Instead of the caret, sometimes an “up arrowhead”    (U+2303, ⌃) is found.
```

Also note that `!` is commonly used for <kbd>Alt</kbd> and `+` is used for <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I always treat `^` as `CTRL`.
Try `CTRL`+`X`.